# Intercept a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Following is my javaScript code.

```
var myObjfn = {
    before : function(){
        console.log("before");
    },
    loadA: function(){
        console.log("loadA");
    },
    loadB: function(){
        console.log("loadB");
    },
    loadC: function(){
        console.log("loadC");
    }
 }
```

Whenever I call myObjfn.loadA(), it should call myObjfn.before() method before executing loadA method. Same for loadB() & loadC(). I don't want to explicitly call before() method in all loadA,loadB and loadC methods. Is there any option to achive this in javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this. Which creates a wrapper function for each function in the object except the `before` function.

```
var myObjfn = { ... };

Object.keys(myObjfn).forEach(key => {
  if (key === "before") return;
  var oldFunc = myObjfn[key];

  myObjfn[key] = function() {
    myObjfn.before();
    return oldFunc.apply(this, arguments);
  };
});

myObjfn.loadA();

// "before"
// "loadA"
```

Comment: Getting following exception Object.keys(...).each is not a function

Comment: I checked with updated answer, same exception. I think it is minor one. I can fix it. I understood your answer which is posted. By the way if you have any idea about '.each is not a function' ?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that, it's `.forEach` instead of `.each`.

Comment: Before that I noticed only oldFunc = myObjfn[key]; Now working fine

Comment: @lcid The actual thing is working. Is there any other optimal way comes in your mind?

Comment: @Prasath Not really, only slightly different versions of my current answer. I would make a separate function for it though (e.g. `attachBeforeHook`). So it becomes `var obj = attachBeforeHook({ before: ..., loadA: ... });` or `var obj = { ... }; obj = attachBeforeHook(obj);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137338/discussion-between-prasath-and-icid).

Comment: Ok no issues. Let me try this.  Thanks for your support.